# MS Access 2016 - Check access level on Openform using Tempvars

Tags: ms-access, vba

My intent is to deny users that do not meet a certain access level access to forms. I initially had issues with error code 3265 while writing the code for:

`TempVars("EmployeeType").Value = rs!EmployeeType_ID.Value`

This is no longer an issue; however, I cannot get access to the form even when the appropriate user is trying to enter. I've checked the spelling of table and column names multiple times as well.

Below is my code for the login (where I'm using the tempvars), followed by the code in form Load().

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Employees", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.txtUserName & "'"

If rs.NoMatch = True Then
    Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = True
    Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = False

If rs!Password <> Me.txtPassword Then
    Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = True
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtUserName) Or IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "You must enter password or login ID.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Required Data"
    Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = False

If rs!EmployeeType >= 4 Then
    Dim prop As Property
    On Error GoTo SetProperty
    Set prop = CurrentDb.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False)

    TempVars("UserName").Value = Me.txtUserName.Value
    TempVars("EmployeeType").Value = rs!EmployeeType_ID.Value

    CurrentDb.Properties.Append prop

SetProperty:
    If MsgBox("Would you like to turn on the bypass key?", vbYesNo, "Allow Bypass") = vbYes Then
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = True
    Else
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = False
    End If

End If

Me.Visible = False
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain"

Globals.LoggingSignOn "Logon"

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.txtUserName = Null
Me.txtPassword = Null
Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
Globals.LoggingSignOn "Logoff"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    If Nz(DLookup("HasAccess", "tbl9EmployeeAccess", "EmployeeType_ID=" & TempVars("EmployeeType") & " FormName='" & Me.Name & "'"), False) = False Then
        MsgBox "You do not have access to access this location."
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time, to anybody that looks into this.

Comment: Have you step debugged? Does the TempVar get set and does it have the value in the Load event? Shouldn't the DLookup include EmployeeID or UserName as part of the search criteria?

Comment: 1. You really need to pare down the code until you find the line that causes the problem. Comment out your logic until the problem goes away, then work back to isolate the problem. 2. When you say "I cannot get the form to load" : what happens? We can't help you unless we know that.

Comment: Note that silent error trapping, like `On Error GoTo SetProperty`, is not going to help you debug your problem. Remove that code, and report any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
June7, the TempVar does not seem to be get set. When I paste the code in the Immediate window I get, "Run-time error 424: Object required."
nicomp, The form won't open because the code is denying access to everybody despite having the correct access. If I remove the "Nz" portion, then it allows access to everybody despite not having the correct access.

I'm fairly new to all of this if it's not obvious, you all have been great. Thanks.

Comment: I feel like I’m making progress. 
1.I have, TempVars("EmployeeType") = rs!EmployeeType_ID.Value in the login form.  
2.In a Globals Module I have: Public Function UserAccess(FormName As String) As Boolean
UserAccess = Nz(DLookup("HasAccess", "tbl9EmployeeAccess", "EmployeeType_ID=" & TempVars("EmployeeType") & " AND 'FormName='" & FormName & "'"), False)  
End Function
3.Form
Private Sub Form_Load()
If Globals.UserAccess(Me.Name) = False Then
MsgBox "You do not have access to access this location."
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

Comment: All of these compile. When I open the form, I am brought to the Globals module (#2) and I get “Run-time error ‘3075’: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ‘EmloyeeType_ID= AND ‘FormName=’frmlockoutTEST”.